# Checar se uma div contém um número

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um parágrafo que contém vários links, alternados entre palavras ou números. Preciso realizar a seguinte checagem: se o link dentro do parágrafo for um texto qualquer, ele não vai fazer nada com o texto, mas caso esse link tenha um número, o mesmo receberá uma formatação CSS.

Vejam:

```html
<p class="teste"><a href="#">Meu texto</a><a href="#">1</a></p>
```

No caso o número 1 deveria receber uma formatação qualquer, e o meu texto não!

Comment: e se acontecer o seguinte: `<a href="#">a1</a>`?

Comment: Olá, na verdade no meu caso não existe essa possibilidade... Só pode ter ou texto ou números, não números com textos!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Se você tiver **apenas** números dentro da tag `a`, pode usar isso:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).html())) {
        $(this).addClass("classeCss");
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Você pode usar cache para fazer a pesquisa mais performática (é sempre importante se preocupar com isso):

```
var cache = $("a");

$(cache).each(function() {
    if ($.isNumeric($(this).html()))
        $(this).addClass("classeCss");
});
```

Segue jsFiddle do [original](http://jsfiddle.net/2rBtT/) e da versão com [cache](http://jsfiddle.net/2rBtT/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Uma forma simples de conseguir isto é utilizando a função nativa **`isNaN`** do Javascript:

```
$('a').each(function(){
   var t = $(this);
    if(!isNaN(t.html())){
         t.addClass('sua-classe');
    }
});
```

Exemplo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/49CAJ/)**

Comment: Bem lembrado, usei a função nativa da `jQuery` porque vi que ele usava a biblioteca. Muito provavelmente, internamente, ela usa esse mesmo método.

Answer (score 5):

Já tens umas respostas muito boas, vou só sugerir uma força de criares uma coleção de objectos com base na verificação pretendida, para dinamizar o teu cenário prático:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/f25qh/)

```
// recolhe elementos que só contém números
var soNumeros = $('a').filter(function() {
   return /^[0-9]*$/.test( $(this).text() );
});

// realiza algo com a colecção de objectos gerada
soNumeros.addClass('bubu');
```

Resultado da adição da classe de CSS `bubu` que altera a formatação do link:

[image: Captura de Tela]

---

Evoluindo a utilização prática deste código, podemos envolver o mesmo numa função que nos permita fazer uso deste método para outros cenários:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/NTem3/)

```
/* Procura elementos que contenham X
 */
function procura (ele, pattern) {
    return ele.filter(function() {
       return pattern.test( $(this).text() );
    });
}

// realiza algo com a colecção de objectos gerada
soNumeros = procura($('a'), /^[0-9]*$/);
soNumeros.addClass('bubu');
```

Desta forma podes passar o selector pretendido e a RegExp a ser utilizada.

Comment: Elegante e de alto nível. Considero sua resposta a melhor.

Comment: Na verdade votei na tua resposta e na do @Kazzkiq porque ambas resolvem o problema do autor. Apenas quis deixar algo mais maleável em termos de utilização. Mas ainda bem que gostaste!

Comment: Não só gostei como aprendi algo novo.